# What libraries/tools exist for developing and running transformations (as in ETL) declaratively?

Tags: xslt, transformation, etl

I've done a fair amount of development work around ETL, and I've come to the conclusion that the best approach to ETL is a declarative one (with support for custom imperative blocks/functions). In particular, declarative approaches allow for visualizations of the transformations, which can make it much easier to discuss the transformations with business/domain experts. Also not to be ignored is the fact that declarative approaches are often more compact and more maintainable.

Unfortunately, the only halfway decent declarative transformation language/framework I've seen is XSLT. And XSLT can be awful for a whole host of other, unrelated reasons. (In particular, its verbosity gets painful on any moderately large transformation project.)

Is XSLT really the only or best game in town for declarative transformations?

I've done some research today, and the only alternatives I've found seem to be largely abandonware:

- [QVT-Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QVT): Seems dead.
- [ATL Transformations](https://www.eclipse.org/atl/atlTransformations/): Seems dead.
- [Eclipse Epsilon Transformation Language](http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/doc/etl/): A "hybrid" of imperative and declarative, and doesn't seem to have any visualization tools.

Any pointers to options or shared wisdom would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

ATL is definetly not dead, you can see the latest information [here](https://eclipse.org/atl/). But they currently work on improving the performance of their execution engine. ATL is mainly a declartive language inspired by QVTr.

QVTr is not completly dead, and the Eclipse QVTd [project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.mmt.qvtd) is actively working on providing a QVTr execution engine. I am not sure if they will eventually support an editor for the visual syntax. If they do, I think the plan is to support [UMLX](http://www.eclipse.org/gmt/umlx/).

ETL, as you point out, is hybrid but that does not mean you have to write hybrid ETL scripts. A pure declarative script will work and the ETL engine will be able to execute it.

IMHO, ATL and ETL are both more than decent declarative transformation languages.

Regarding the visual syntax, I would suggest that you could craete your own notation and craete an editor to support it using [Sirius](https://eclipse.org/sirius/). From there you can use a model transformation to generate the equivalent ETL/ATL code, and then run that :) (either a model-to-model to create an AST or a model-to-code to generate the script). The benefit of defining your own visual syntax is that you can tailor it to fit your audience making sure it helps you discuss the transformation with them.

Answer (score 0):

I also do find that a declarative approach works really well (as I explained in an article [here](http://thibautbarrere.com/2015/04/05/how-to-write-solid-data-processing-code/)). I say this since I've been maintaining code-based declarative ETL for the last 10 years, first using the now unmaintained [activewarehouse-etl](https://github.com/activewarehouse/activewarehouse-etl), and since 2015 using [Kiba ETL](http://www.kiba-etl.org/) which I wrote and open-sourced.

I'm pretty sure other declarative code-based ETL exist, too!